# Facebook Application Post to Wall

Tags: php, facebook

I want to post some info along with an icon about my facebook app on the users Wall as soon as he give the permission. The app is created in iframe and I want to use Graph API. I have done this before but the facebook SDK recently changed.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting to a users wall without an explicit interaction where they allow you to do so [Facebook Platform Policy] (http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId, // YOUR APP ID
    'secret' => $apiSecret, // YOUR API SECRET
    'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) { 
    $attachment = array(
        'name' => 'NAME',
        'caption' => 'CAPTION',
        'link' => 'http://yourlink.com',
        'description' => 'DESCRIPTION',
        'picture' => 'http://yourlink.com/yourimage.jpg'
    );
    try { $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment); } catch (Exception $e) {  }
}
```

Comment: I got this

`Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession()`

Comment: Sorry `Facebook::getSession()` is from the pre v3 SDK. I've updated the code for the latest version of the SDK.